# Can gprbuild be configured to output gnatprep preprocessed sources?

Tags: ada, gprbuild

I have a gpr project which uses gnatprep to preprocess source files. But now I have a tool which needs the already preprocessed source files. I know that I can hunt down each source file and run it through gnatprep:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.ad[sb]' -exec gnatprep -DSymbol=value {} {}.prep \;
```

But I'd like to leverage the project file to find the right source files and pass them through. My project file also defines the various symbol values to use, which I would have to add to the command above. Is it possible through some parameter in the .gpr file? E.g.

```
   for Object_Dir use 'obj';
   for Preprocessed_Sources_Dir use 'wow_that_was_easy';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell the compiler to leave the preprocessed sources in the `Object_Dir` with the `-gnateG` option, like so, in the project file:

```
   package Compiler is
      for Default_Switches ("Ada") use ("-gnateDFoo=""Bar""", "-gnateG" );
   end Compiler;
```

The preprocessed source will then be named `<original_filename>.prep`, for example `foo.adb` -> `foo.adb.prep`

Edit:

For your followup-question, you'd have to put the preprocessor options in a separate file, for example `prep.def`:

```
* -u -c -DFoo="Bar"
```

or, if you want to specify options per file:

```
"foo.adb" -u -c -DFoo="Bar"
```

And then tell the compiler to use that file with the `gnatep=` option:

```
package Compiler is
   for Default_Switches ("Ada") use ("-gnateG", "-gnatep=" & Foo'Project_Dir & "prep.def" );
end Compiler;
```

Comment: I also want to pass `gnatprep -c` to leave removed sections as comments. But `-gnatec` or `-gnateC` does not work; is there any way to pass gnatprep flags from the gpr file?

Comment: Thank you, that works. Note it is also possible to keep the `-gnateDFoo=Bar` in the gprfile, having only the -c option in prep.def